# Send an email to multiple email addresses retrieved from the database in PHP

Tags: php, email, variables, phpmailer

So i have had this issue which I’ve been trying to solve.. 
I have a list of customers emails retrieved from the database and once i click Process, it supposes to send an email to "the customer's email".. The screenshot below describes what i mean..

So once you press the "Process" button on the first row, it should send an email to the retrieved email in the first row 
[image]

```
    // The code below retrieves all the customer info from the database including customers email addresses. 
    <?php
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    print "<tr>";
    print  "<td>" . $row['TransactionID'] . "</td>";
    print  "<td>" .$row['ItemName']."<br>" ."</td>";
    print  "<td>" .$row['ItemQTY']."<br>" ."</td>";
    print  "<td>" . $row['ItemAmount'] . "</td>";
    print  "<td>" . $row['BuyerEmail'] . "</td>";
    print "<td ><a href='#sendemail'>Process</a></td>"; //Once this link is clicked, it should take me to the next code send an email the retrieved email. 


    print  "</tr>";
}
$mysqli->close();


?>
```

//---------------------//

```
// The code below should trigger once i click "Process" and send an email to the customer. 
if (isset($_GET['sendemail'])){

require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                   
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                        
SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                       
authentication
$mail->Username = '****@gmail.com';          
$mail->Password = '********'; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                         
`ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                 

$mail->setFrom('****@gmail.com', 'RANDOMNAME');
$mail->addReplyTo('****@gmail.com', 'RANDOMNAME');
$mail->addAddress('BuyerEmail');  


$mail->isHTML(true); 

$bodyContent = '<h1>Our Valued Customer,</h1>';
$bodyContent .= '<p>Your Order is ready for pick up!</p>';

$mail->Subject = 'RANDOMNAME';
$mail->Body    = $bodyContent;

if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message could not be sent.';
  echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
runsendemail();



}
   ?>
```

The code works just fine when $mail->addAddress('email@example'); has a predefined value..  but not sure how to make it 'variable' meaning it keeps changing according to the list of emails retrieved from the database..

Answer (score 0):

Your process link should link to the page containing your mail logic and pass along the email to use `<a href="/sendmail.php?sendemail=<?php echo urlencode($row['BuyerEmail']); ?>">Process</a>`

Your sendmail.php file then can receive the email with `$_GET['sendemail']`  and continue with your mailing logic `$mail->addAddress(urldecode($_GET['sendemail']));`.

Note:  Hopefully you have some kind of authentication in place and this isn't a publicly accessible page otherwise anybody can trigger this file and send your database information to an email of their choosing, or hit this file a ton of times and crash your system.

Answer (score 0):

Change this to the following :

```
  print "<td ><a href='#sendemail'>Process</a></td>"; //Once this link is clicked, it should take me to the next code send an email the retrieved email.
```

This is some thing you should change it to :

```
echo "
<td>
<form method='get' action='CHANGE IT TO YOUR PHP SCRIPT NAME'?
<input type='hidden' name='sendemail' value='$row['BuyerEmail']'>
<input type='submit' value='Process'>
</form>
</td>
";
```

Here I have used a html simple form. I'm passing a hidden value that is your buyer email using get method. Change the action to your php script name if it is a different file.  Now you can use $_GET['sendemail'] in your email sending code as buyer's email address.